# can i use react native for android tv app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-tv

I just want to know that we can use react native framework for android tv application.In the doc react native say text input focus not working is there any way to use text input with android tv and also want to know how much code changes when create android tv app with react native.
thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Yes. React Native have support for lots of platform. Here is the commit : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b7bb2e5745f2bdbfeeccef8d97d469730942e01c

Also for code changes, there will some changes but core components will be same. You can checkout starter project here : https://github.com/DCKT/react-native-androidtv